# Computehash method in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using the below code to compare password from database.

```
using (var hmac = new HMACSHA512())
{
    var computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));                
    using (var hmac1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512())
    {
        var computedHash1 = hmac1.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
    }
    var computedSalt = hmac.Key;
    for (int i = 0; i < computedHash.Length; i++)
    {
        if (computedHash[i] != passwordHash[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

On analysis I found that, when we create a new object of `HMACSHA512()`, it creates a new computed hash, because of which the password from database fails to match the ComputedHash.
As seen above, "computedHash" and "computedHash1" are different for the same string.

Comment: Why are you inventing your own authentication system? The fact you're using HMACSHA512 for it means that you shouldn't, it's not the right tool for the job. It's a message signing algorithm, not a safe password hashing algorithm. Just use Identity for account management.

Comment: You're never giving your hasher a seed. Meaning it will theoretically never hash the same string the same way twice.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes I agree, I was just trying out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the parameterless constructor, which is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha512.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Security_Cryptography_HMACSHA512__ctor) with:

> With this constructor, a 64-byte, randomly generated key is used.

Basically, you should be supplying a key for the hash - if you supply the same key to the constructor each time you create a hash, you'll get back the same results each time.

You can check that with your existing code by giving `hmac1` the same key as `hmac`:

```cs
using (var hmac1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512(hmac.Key))
```